# Python Selenium import cookies

Tags: python, selenium, cookie, импорт

Здраствуйте, появился такой вопрос, возможно ли выгрузить из обычного браузера куки файл и засунуть его в браузер Selenium? Я не совсем представляю как такое написать поэтому спрашиваю тут.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вручную засунуть куки в этот браузер (я имею ввиду переместить в директорию), если всё пройдёт удачно (всё может пройти удачно, так как у многих браузеров схожие системы), то можете спокойно приступать к написанию кода. Я понятия не имею об этот браузере, но если куки можно перенести путём копирования их в директорию, то можно без всяких проблем написать программу на python: просто вводить путь к куки, и путь к нужной директории, и просто переместить туда куки